# Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync is inconsistent if item.saveAsync is called right after

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Here is the code that reproduces the issue in Script Lab:

```
$("#run").click(run);
let callbackCount = 0;
function run() 
{
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://ow2.res.office365.com/owalanding/2021.4.9.04/images/outlook-icon.jpg", "test.jpg", () => { console.log(callbackCount++)});
    
    // If the following line is commented, the issue will be resolved. 
    Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync((res) => { console.log(res) });
  }
}
```

The above code results in only two or three attachments getting attached to the compose pane. As mentioned in the code, this issue is resolved if `item.saveAsync` is not called in the loop.

Another point to be noted is that the callback for `item.saveAsync` runs only once instead of ten times.

This issue was reproduced on:

- New Outlook for Mac v16.52 (21080101)
- macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

This issue **cannot** be reproduced on Old Outlook for Mac. The attachment gets attached ten times, as expected, on Old Outlook for Mac.

Comment: Try to place the `SaveAsync` call to the `addFileAttachmentAsync's` callback instead. Do you get the same results?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Calling saveAsync inside the callback does not reproduce the problem, but we have intentionally written this code to simulate an issue we are facing in our flow. Due to multiple events occurring simultaneously, `saveAsync` and `addFileAttachmentAsync` are called parallelly in different events.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug on the OfficeJS repo in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

We acknowledge that this might be an issue in this exact flow of code, however, saveAsync should be called in the callback of addFileAttachmentAsync. Calling saveAsync multiple times synchronously without waiting for addFileAttachmentAsync to finish leads to an inconsistent state due to each of the asynchronous calls finishing in unpredictable order. Can we understand if you have any specific scenario where you exactly need this flow of code to work?

Comment: In any case, we have added this issue to our backlog. Thanks for reporting this issue. Unfortunately, we have no timelines to share at this point.